# Arrow keys turn into control characters in Telnet

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, telnet, arrow-keys, control-characters

I'm in an Ubuntu terminal, and telnet to a server. Now whenever I type 'up', it turns into ^[[A. Other arrow keys also turn into control characters. Is there a way I can run telnet so it understands my arrow keys? This would be a huge help because I'd like to scroll up in my commands history.

Answer (score 1):

It's not telnet that needs to understand the escape sequences your keys produce; it's whatever program you're typing them into at the remote end. Looks like your `$TERM` environment variable (on the remote system) is not getting set correctly for the terminal you're running telnet in.

It's been a while since I used telnet for logins, but IIRC it doesn't transfer `TERM` automatically, so you may have to set it yourself. Or, as Mike C suggests, use ssh instead -- that does transfer `TERM`.

Comment: Consider also the security implications. Telnet is inherently insecure, so your connection is vulnerable unless you add extra layers of security, such as VPN--and even that will only protect you from attacks from outside your office network.

Answer (score -1):

I would either SSH into the server instead of telnet, or use [puTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).