# Node JS REPL, Sockets, and Telnet - Tab Completion, Arrow Keys, etc

Tags: node.js, telnet, read-eval-print-loop, control-characters

I have been playing around with Node's REPL. I thought it would be pretty cool to make it available via a Socket, connect to it via Telnet/puTTY/whatever, and debug my server on-the-fly.

I used the example found here: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/repl.html, which basically looks like this...

```
net.createServer(function (socket) {
  var cmd = repl.start(">", socket);
  //... some other stuff here.... not important
}).listen(5001);
```

OK, great! Now I can connect to port 5001 with Telnet and interact with the REPL. But, I am running into issues with control characters (i.e. Tab, Ctrl+C, up arrow, down arrow, etc.). How can I get these to work?  For example, if I connect using telnet, type "1+1<Enter>", I get 2.  But, then when I hit "<Up Arrow><Enter>", I get "...", as if the REPL is waiting for me to finish the command.  But, really, all I want to do is see the last command that I executed. I know Telnet likes to hold onto its output until a line feed is inputted, but is there any way to avoid this, as well?

```
$ telnet localhost 6634
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
>1+1
2
>^[[A
...
```

**EDIT**: I also found this issue, which may or may not be related - [Arrow keys turn into control characters in Telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247986/arrow-keys-turn-into-control-characters-in-telnet)

**EDIT 2**: Hmmm... `rlwrap` seems to solve most of my problem:

```
$ rlwrap telnet localhost 6634
```

Only thing that doesn't work is tab completions of local/global variables, which I suppose I can live without. I was mostly concerned with the command history. `rlwrap` is neat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See above.

`rlwrap telnet localhost 6634`

Comment: you could mimic tab completion using the -c -f switches: http://blog.lishman.com/2008/04/rlwrap.html obviously you'll need a node.js keyword list

Answer (score 0):

To get the built-in tab completion and history in REPLServer working on a socket you need to explicitly provide the `terminal: true` option when instantiating REPLServer to tell it behave as if it's connected to a terminal, and then on the client side you put the terminal in raw mode (see e.g. `repl-client` on npm).