# Why _ as variable name in node REPL mode to require failed

Tags: node.js

Node version v5.4.1 and I installed lodash in current directory's node_modules. And I encouter this issue where '_' seems special.

```
> var _ = require('lodash');
undefined
> _.defaults
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)
> var l = require('lodash');
undefined
> l.defaults
[Function]
>
```

I saw [a question related to undefined output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260605/how-to-require-node-module-in-node-repl-without-installing-globally). But no question yet cares about the failure of 'require' when '_' as variable name. Do you know any about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underscore is a special variable that [holds the result of the most recent expression](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/repl.html#repl_assignment_of_the_underscore_variable). Prior to node v6.0.0, this behavior could not be disabled. However, node v6.0.0 introduced [a change](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/ad8257fa5b9795d3d79fa4a91d0f18c43f024ab3) that allowed the underscore variable to be overwritten. So you will need to upgrade your copy of node if you want to reassign the `_` variable in the node REPL.